# Time and Space complexity of String Concatenation in C++

Tags: c++

```
x = x+x
x+=x
x.append(x)
```

Are the three ways above the same (thinking of time and space complexity)

I’m thinking using “+” creates a new string while append just adds to the existing string, so append is faster and less space usage.

This is a questions that is more theory/knowledge based...

Comment: Are you talking about `std::string`?

Comment: Even if it were different, in practice it'll be optimized out.

Comment: Don't spam the language tags! You poject uses a single language version.

Comment: The upper limits on complexity for member functions and operator overloads are specified and a reference is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: In the end, look at generated assembly (godbolt.org) with various optimization levels, and in practice use a profiler (if you really have a perfomance issue). For C++20 I expect std::format("{}{}", x); to perform well.  If you need repeated concatenations consider using std::ostringstream.

Comment: @lorro [Will it](https://godbolt.org/z/qGh6aTTse)?

Comment: @Evg Thanks for making the godbolt example (now I don't have to) ;)

Comment: @user17732522 Oops, meant Evg ofcourse. Still your link was interesting to me too, In the sense I never really realized complexity was stated too

Comment: Here's one implementation of +=: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/string#L1131-L1133

Comment: @Evg Very nice, mostly with -O0 (compiler optimisations disabled), in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling three (actually four) different functions: `operator=(s)`, `operator+(s)`, `operator+=(s)` and `append(s)`, and the time and space requirements (and concerns) will depend on the exact code of these functions. There's no generic answer to your question. Even for a given class, like `std::string`, it would be implementation dependant.

Please note that in the first case (`x=x+x`), you're doing two operations (that is, calling two functions). And also note that `operator=(s)`, `operator+=(s)` and `append(s)` act directly on a *reference* to the main object (I'm talking about the `this`, and not about the additional parameter). The [reference manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) for `operator+=(s)` and `append(s)` states *"Complexity: There are no standard complexity guarantees, typical implementations behave similar to std::vector::insert."*

The idea of `append()` being faster because it "just adds to the existing string" could be right if the "existing string" had reserved space (which is not the case).